# Errors with binary search in Haskell

Tags: haskell, beginner, binary-search

I just learned about `Maybe` in Haskell, so I decided to try to use it with a binary search.

Here's the function:

```
binarySearch :: (Ord a, Int b) => [a] -> a -> b -> b -> Maybe b

binarySearch l e beg last
 | lookat < e = (binarySearch l e i last)
 | lookat > e = (binarySearch l e beg i)
 | lookat == e = Just i
 | otherwise = Nothing
 where i = floor ((beg+last)/2)
       lookat = l !! i
```

`l` is a list, `e` is the element of interest, `beg` is the start of
the section of interest and `end` is the end of said section. The error I am getting is:

```
BinarySearch.hs:1:25:
    `Int' is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for `binarySearch':
      binarySearch :: (Ord a, Int b) => [a] -> a -> b -> b -> Maybe b
```

I have tried a few other things including:

```
binarySearch :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> Maybe b
```

Yielding the error:

```
BinarySearch.hs:6:23:
    Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
    from the context (Ord a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 binarySearch :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> Maybe b
      at BinarySearch.hs:(3,1)-(9,22)
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            binarySearch :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> Maybe b
          at BinarySearch.hs:3:1
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `i'
    In the expression: Just i
    In an equation for `binarySearch':
        binarySearch l e beg last
          | lookat < e = (binarySearch l e i last)
          | lookat > e = (binarySearch l e beg i)
          | lookat == e = Just i
          | otherwise = Nothing
          where
              i = floor ((beg + last) / 2)
              lookat = l !! i
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any corrections or comments on style or solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `Int b`, you just want `Int`:

```
Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
```

Comment: Thank you! To make it fully work I also had to get rid of `float` and use `quot` instead of `/` when calculating `i`